# How to list YouTube Video Recommendations. Using express.js and ejs

Tags: node.js, express, ejs, youtube-data-api

I'm having a problem listing video recommendations. What I'm trying to do is display video recommendations based on the video currently playing.

**Let me explain the code:
**The code snippet is taken from my pages/watch.ejs file. After searching for the video on pages/search.ejs, it goes to pages/watch.ejs with the video id and title in the url. The video then plays. Now I need to have recommended videos displayed under the video playing and for the next video to play after the current vidoe had played if it's not on loop (replaying the video over and over again).

I tried doing this

```
                // Fetch YouTube recommendations
                function fetchYouTubeRecommendations(videoId) {
                    var apiKey = 'YOUTUBE_API_KEY'; // Replace with your YouTube API key
                    var apiUrl = 'https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search';
                    var maxResults = 10;

                    console.log('Video ID:', videoId);
                    console.log('API Key:', apiKey);

                    console.log('API URL:', `${apiUrl}?part=snippet&relatedToVideoId=${videoId}&type=video&maxResults=${maxResults}&key=${apiKey}`);

                    fetch(`${apiUrl}?part=snippet&relatedToVideoId=${videoId}&type=video&maxResults=${maxResults}&key=${apiKey}`)
                        .then(response => {
                            if (!response.ok) {
                                throw new Error('Network response was not ok');
                            }
                            return response.json();
                        })
                        .then(data => {
                            if (data.items && data.items.length > 0) {
                                displayRecommendations(data.items);
                            } else {
                                console.error('No recommendations found.');
                            }
                        })
                        .catch(error => console.error('Error fetching recommendations:', error));
                }

                // Display YouTube recommendations
                function displayRecommendations(items) {
                    var recommendationsContainer = document.getElementById('recommendationsContainer');
                    recommendationsContainer.innerHTML = ''; // Clear existing recommendations

                    items.forEach(item => {
                        var recommendation = document.createElement('div');
                        recommendation.className = 'recommendation';

                        // Create an anchor element for the video link
                        var videoLink = document.createElement('a');
                        videoLink.href = '/watch/' + item.id.videoId; // Adjust the URL structure as needed

                        var thumbnailUrl = item.snippet.thumbnails.medium.url;
                        var videoTitle = item.snippet.title;

                        var thumbnailImage = document.createElement('img');
                        thumbnailImage.src = thumbnailUrl;
                        thumbnailImage.alt = videoTitle;

                        videoLink.appendChild(thumbnailImage);
                        recommendation.appendChild(videoLink);

                        recommendationsContainer.appendChild(recommendation);
                    });
                }
```